# Most customizable Lightbox plug-in for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am searching for a simplistic jQuery Lightbox plugin with minimal features.

- Must support Ajax / Inline / Images
- Must have a close button.
- Must be easily customizable (CSS wise). I tried a bunch of plugins and they have so much unnecessary styling.
- Must have a close button in the top right corner.
- Must be a jQuery plug-in.

I could write it myself, but it is a bit of time-crunch right now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

ThickBox offers versatility (images, iframed content, inline content, and AJAX content).

Comment: ThickBox seems to be just versatile enough.  I keep thinking I'll hit a situation where it won't suffice, but so far I haven't.

Comment: Changed selected answer. Nyromodal had too many little bugs - still being kinked out by the developer. Thickbox server my needs with minimal customization.

Answer (score 3):

http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/

Comment: Seems perfect for my needs will try and come back.

Comment: Using this, requires a bit of work to get the shader working full-screen in IE6, but had that problem before will e-mail dev with a solution. 

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I've never seen this lightbox before... it looks very nice :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/example) will work for you. It does support Ajax, inline, iframe and images, have a close button in the upper right corner and is a jQuery plug-in. Looks good too, but I haven't customized it.

Comment: Fancy box was good with the positioning etc, but the styles and the markup were rather convoluted. There is around 8 divs just for the shadows, and a weird structure for the lightbox background. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)?

Comment: Hey, thank you! Unfortunately not what I was looking for, need least rearranging (eg. close button),plus need the total shader background.

Comment: Actually, if you look in the facebox.js, you'll see you can assign the facebox any HTMl you want with the `faceboxHtml` option as well as the background overlay/shader `overlay: true`